# Architecture KMM + Firebase Auth

Tags: android, ios, firebase, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

would anyone be available to explain to me how to use the Firebase SDK library from GitLive on a KMM project?
Especially the architecture to set up for Firebase Auth.
I'am totally lost

I try to follow some firebase tuto and kmm tuto

Comment: Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but I think it is worth taking a look at this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91). Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Answer (score 1):

I use GitLive Auth + GitLive Firestore in my KMM project. It's not a huge integration, but it's a good template/base point to get started from: [KMM-Firebase-Messaging](https://github.com/santansarah/KMM-Firebase-Messaging)

1. Add the dependencies to commonMain
2. Export the pods in your `cocoapods` block:

```
pod("FirebaseFirestore", linkOnly = true)
pod("FirebaseUI/Google")
pod("FirebaseUI/OAuth")
```

3. Create a User Repository in commonMain - just like you would for your Android app. Here, the functions are very similar to using Firebase Auth: [UserRepository](https://github.com/santansarah/KMM-Firebase-Messaging/blob/main/shared/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/santansarah/kmmfirebasemessaging/data/local/UserRepository.kt)